# How to get screen resolution of other attached monitors

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screen

I am trying to get the Screen resolutions for all the attached physical monitor. I am able to get the screen resolution of primary monitor using Win API GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN). I am wondering how can i get the similar resolution value of other moniotrs

Comment: You have to [enumerate the monitors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) SM_CXSCREEN / SM_CYSCREEN gets the primary monitor resolution. May also use GetDeviceCaps. SM_CX/YVIRTUALSCREEN will get size for all monitors.

[SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) SPI_GETWORKAREA will get the work area size on a monitor i.e. the size excluding taskbar and docked bars

[GetMonitorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901(v=vs.85).aspx) gets you the the size of specific monitor.